# DynamoDB Global Tables replication delay

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use DynamoDB Global Tables, what is the typical/average delay before data will be replicated?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(Answering this myself, because when I needed, I could not find the answer here):

Its usually about 2000ms, we had several load tests in Oregon us-west-2 (with on-demand pricing DynamoDB) with up to 30 000 requests per minute and this is how it behaves (you can see that these 2000ms is standard even when no load tests were performed). Some spikes can happen as well, so dont rely on that fully:

[image: DynamoDB Global Tables Replication Delay]